# Cambiar comando Atom para compilar

Tags: atom-editor

Buenas a todos!

Veréis, si me voy en Atom a Preferencias => Keybindings tengo el siguiente comando:

**keystroke  |   Command                   | Source           | Selector**

**f5         |   gpp-compiler:compile      | Gpp Compiler     | atom-text-editor**

Si me voy al archivo de keymap para editar que en lugar de F5 sea otro comando, ¿cómo debería de ponerlo en ese archivo?

Gracias!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cambiando el valor de f5? ¬.¬

Comment: @DavidG. Gracias por responder, claro que es obvio, pero tendría que añadirlo al archivo del keybinding y no sé qué tengo que poner en ese archivo. He añadido imágenes para que se pueda entender mejor. En la primera, lo que quiero cambiar y en la segunda el archivo que habría que añadir si no me equivoco el keybinding. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es en el KeyBindings darle clic al icono que aparece al lado del **KeyBindings** (círculo rojo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después dale clic a **your keymap file** (línea naranja), para que te lleve a la segunda imagen que tienes como referencia que es el archivo **keymap.cson**. En esa pestaña vas hasta la última línea del documento y pegas lo que copiaste del KeyBindings que en mi caso esta señalado con el rectángulo verde:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que tienes que hacer es reemplazar el shortcut por el de tu preferencia, por ejemplo en mi imagen el Tree-View tiene el shortcute `ctrl-*`, cambialo por el shortcute que tu quieras, recuerda que si quieres hacer combinación de teclas debes separarlas con un guion medio.